# Beautifulsoup - Find an item by string in HTML with regex

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Consider this case with following HTML. I'd like to get the item with `Billing Address:` in it.

HTML:

```
[...]
<p style="line-height:1.0; "></p></span><span style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;"><u style="font-family:Arial; font-size:9.5pt; ">Billing Address:
    <p style="line-height:1.0; "></p></u><p></p></span><span style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;">Customer number: </span><span style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;">000001234
    <p style="line-height:1.0; "></p></span><span style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;">xxxx<br>yyyy<br>zzzz</span>
[...]
```

My code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("C:\Temp\email.html") as fp:  # this is input html file
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

        
tmp_soup = soup.find_all("u", string=re.compile(r'Billing Address:.*'))
print(tmp_soup)

[Out]:
[]
```

It returns no item, but what's wrong with it?

I've searched for similar issues but cannot find answers which can help me in this specific case.

Comment: Do your whole tags, wrapped in a single parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** *While pattern will be applayed to all `u`, it is not clear what .string should referred to, so .string is defined to be None.*

---

An alternativ approache to `re` module is selecting with `css selectors` and `BeautifulSoup` directly:

```
soup.select('u:-soup-contains("Billing Address:")')
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<p style="line-height:1.0; "></p></span><span style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;"><u style="font-family:Arial; font-size:9.5pt; ">Billing Address:
<p style="line-height:1.0; "></p></u><p></p></span><span style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;">Customer number: </span><span style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;">000001234
<p style="line-height:1.0; "></p></span><span style="font-size:9.5pt; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;">xxxx<br>yyyy<br>zzzz</span>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

print(soup.select('u:-soup-contains("Billing Address:")'))
```

#### Output

```
[<u style="font-family:Arial; font-size:9.5pt; ">Billing Address:
 <p style="line-height:1.0; "></p></u>]
```